# How to build the feature vector from sentence for intent classification in NLU?

Tags: classification, natural-language, feature-engineering

I am trying to develop a NLU (natural language understanding) engine which interprets human language utterance to intent and slots. After some searching, I found this very useful question for NLU novice like me: [How to proceed with NLP task for recognizing intent and slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624672/how-to-proceed-with-nlp-task-for-recognizing-intent-and-slots)

In the answer, @darshan says:

> ...use a classifier to do the same using feature vector formulated
>   from the input sentence.

I know that after transforming the sentence to a feature vector will be very useful for classification task. But **how should we get such a feature vector?**

For instance, the sentences: `What's the weather today?` `What's it like out?` `How's the weather?` all should be classified to a `weather_query` intent. But how to make these sentences into numerical feature vectors?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build a classifier for each intent and then use that to find any given intent in a sentence. For starters, work using a rule based system such as using a keywords or regex. Then once you've enough sentences go forward with the machine learning classifier and keep improving it.